# How to change the precision of UWP Telerik RadDataGrid DataGridNumericalColumn editor

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, telerik

I'm using the Telerik UWP RadDatagrid inside my application. There's a column that contains integers in the item source that is bound to the datagrid. This displays correctly i.e. 1 displays as 1.  However the cell editor seems to use a double rather than an int.  Therefore if i click away from the cell with 1 entered rather than 1.00 it doesn't commit the change.

Is there a way to specify the precision of the inline editor to be an integer rather than a double for the DataGridNumericalColumn ?

Answer (score 0):

The editor of the [Numerical Column](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/universal-windows-platform/controls/raddatagrid/columns/datagrid-numericalcolumn) is a
[`RadNumericBox`](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/universal-windows-platform/controls/radnumericbox/overview). The value format is defined by the `ValueFormat` property, that the default value is `{0,0:N2}` defined by [`RadNumericBox.cs`](https://github.com/telerik/UI-For-UWP/blob/master/Controls/Input/Input.UWP/NumericBox/RadNumericBox.cs). Which will just show like "1:00". Actually update the `ValueFormat` to `{}{0:N0}` will meet your requirements. You could add a `RadNumericBox` to check the result.

```
    <input:RadNumericBox
        x:Name="numericBox2"
        AllowNullValue="False"
        ValueFormat="{}{0:N0}"
        Watermark="Fill in the field" />

    <input:RadNumericBox
        x:Name="numericBox3"
        AllowNullValue="False"
        ValueFormat="{}{0:N2}"
        Watermark="Fill in the field" />
```

Since the  [`Numerical Column`](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/universal-windows-platform/controls/raddatagrid/columns/datagrid-numericalcolumn) does't provide a `ValueFormat` property, so unfortunately you may need to re-write the Telerik package to implement your own `DataGridNumericalColumn` (Or simple to just change the default value for `RadNumercBox` but may be not recommended). For detail implementation please try it yourself.

Comment: This does not work. Changing the `ValueFormat` for `DataGridNumericalColumn` as describes makes it DISPLAY correctly, but when the editor comes up it is still the default format.